# Changing render target within an effect

Tags: c++, directx9

I've got an effect which is a fairly simple two-pass deal- but it involves rendering to a texture in the first pass. Is it possible to change the render target from within an effect? I would definitely appreciate the reduction in code duplication from C++ by being able to do both passes within HLSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't do this -- you have to change the render target between passes from the CPU side of things. The [list of effect states that can be manipulated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by effect files does not include anything regarding the render target.